# On a polar plot (using matplotlib) can a new point use a previous point as the centre of origin?

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I've been modeling a double pendulum (here is a good example https://web.mit.edu/jorloff/www/chaosTalk/double-pendulum/double-pendulum-en.html) in python and I have got to the stage of refining my code. So far I have been plotting the pendulum on a standard graph using Cartesian coordinates; however, I thought it might be neat if I could use a polar plot, given that the data I'm generating is in polar coordinates. In the image below I have theta1, theta2, L1 and L2.

At the moment I have a solution using maths but this is less understandable and more complicated than the original method. My question is whether it is possible to create a polar plot only using the data in the image (theta1, theta2, L1 and L2). For this I can plot the first point using L1 and theta1, but for the second point I need to use L2 and theta2 which I am finding difficult because instead of using the centre of origin I would need to plot this point from the previous point.

[image]

- the length of each rod.
- the angle of each pendulum (0 radians = vertical downwards, counter-clockwise is positive)

I realise this might not be possible as have already spent a while scanning the internet.

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking to plot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.